# Java Applet Viewer - Disable Security Manager

Tags: java, applet

I am using an applet and I don't want to sign it right now so how do I disable the security manager from the applet viewer?

That way I can work faster. :)

Comment: *"That way I can work faster"* ... and leave all of your security issues to closer to your deadline :-)

Comment: Oh, but I can fix those BEFORE I release it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`appletviewer -J"-Djava.security.policy=all.policy"
writeFile.html`

From http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/applets/